# MVVM navigation how to

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I dont hope to get any answer but i will try to be clear.

I tried **Caliburn Micro** . At first it seemed fine and all i need. Some features yes but other not.

All i wanted is a single window with some views as usercontrols and multiple dialogs at each view. Using a **conductor.OneActive** i could achieve the first with little pain. However switching between views even looking the example was to cast Parent to Conductor and call a method there.
Even example of caliburn micro did casting like this. Calling .close(false) at screen was same as close(true) resulting in killing the view and recreating causing lag in lowest end atom pc. 
So only solution was to cast to parent.

**Dialogs**
I tried tons of dialogs examples but non worked and made my life hard.
Messagebox etc were DEAD easy but in case you wanted multiple dialogs you were out of luck.
If you put code at close callback to open another dialog you got bonus stackoverflow exception as it gets confused.(Endless loop). 
I could figure a good dialog that could cache the view and at the same time to display efficiently multiple dialogs.

**Event Aggregrator**
Also i cant figure out how on earth event aggregrator is suitable for switching views. In case you have multiple conductors it could be a hell to manage.

Comment: Personally I would have a `DialogsViewModel` of some kind that contains a collection of `IDialogViewModel` objects, and give other `ViewModels` some way to send an `IDialogViewModel` object to it (`EventAggregator` is the first thing that comes to mind). Then I'd create a View that was meant to display the entire collection of `IDialogViewModels` whenever it wasn't empty. It could be a Popup, a UserControl, or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

To show a dialog - as in Modal Dialog that blocks the view that showed it - you should be using `IWindowManager.ShowDialog`.

Comment: i know this but this displays a new window.In order to display it correctly i would have to get current window size and set it accordingly.

Comment: @Parhs: In that case you might want to add some screen samples of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at prism library http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

see navigation chapter:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

But I don't know how EventAggregator could help you to switch views… you could subscribe to received an event on a closingView but… …

Comment: EventAggregator can help you switch views by listening for a SwitchView message.  You message the conductor and say, switch to ABCView.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Catel](http://www.catelproject.com). It has a [UIVisualizerService](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/UIVisualizerService) which allows you to show windows based on their view model.

It also has a [ViewManager (IViewManager)](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Finding+the+view+of+a+view+model) which allows you to manage all views inside your whole application. Besides that, it also provides a ViewModelManager (IViewModelManager) which does the same for your view models. Best of all: you can find all views that are connected to a specific view model in your application to interact with that.